# Как вести логгирование с Log4j в maven проекте?

Tags: intellij-idea, maven, tomcat, log4j

Как запускать проект maven, чтобы логи записывались в файл? Когда я разворачиваю приложение через tomcat redeploy файл не создается.
Файл log4j.xml выглядит так

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
    <log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

    <appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="append" value="false"/>
        <param name="maxFileSize" value="2MB"/>
        <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="1"/>
        <param name="file" value="TravelAgencyLogging.txt"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%l %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="debug"/>
        <appender-ref ref="file"/>
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

В классах использую Logger так:

```
    private static final Logger LOGGER;

    static {
        LOGGER = Logger.getRootLogger();
    }

    public void init() {
        LOGGER.debug("servlet init");
    }
```

При этом, если просто создаю какой-то класс с main методом в котором есть logger, то тогда logger работает. 
В pom.xml файле зависимости подгружены. Работаю в idea, сервер tomcat.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>by.javatr.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>TravelAgency</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.14.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.15</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>http://localhost:8081/manager/text</url>
                    <server>TomcatServer</server>
                    <path>/TravelAgency</path>
                    <username>admin</username>
                    <password>admin</password>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Ошибок не вылетает. Я так понимаю, что дело в том как запускать проект, не могу разобраться.